# Traversing Two XMLs in getting intersection of data in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have two xmls like below. i want to return the first xml in which ids are matched with second xml.

```
DECLARE 
  @x xml, 
  @y xml

SET @x = '<roots><root><id>1</id><name>rp</name></root><root><id>2</id><name>pr</name></root><root><id>3</id><name>rrp</name></root></roots>'

SET @y = '<root><id>1</id><id>5</id><id>6</id></root>'


output: <roots><root><id>1</id><name>rp</name></root></roots>
```

i am able to acheive this with loop. But is there any simple way to do this.

Comment: please post the loop solution!

Answer (score 1):

Shred `@x` on `roots/root` and extract the XML and the value for `id`.
Check against @y in the where clause using [`exist()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189869.aspx) and [`sql:column()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191214.aspx).

```sql
select X.root
from (
     select X.X.query('*') as root,
            X.X.value('(id/text())[1]', 'int') as id
     from @x.nodes('/roots/root') as X(X)
     )
     as X
where @y.exist('/root/id/text()[. = sql:column("X.id")]') = 1
for xml path(''), root('roots')
```

Result:

```xml
<roots>
  <root>
    <id>1</id>
    <name>rp</name>
  </root>
</roots>
```